# Which flight search engine lets one filter based on transit/via-point?

Tags: air-travel, transit, international-travel, flight-search-engines

I am looking for a flight search engine that lets one filter flights by transit/via-point besides travel destination.

[image]

Like the one that's shown in the above image.

I tried popular travel portals like makemytrip.com, cleartip.com, yatra.com etc but I couldn't find the facility.

Any ideas?

Comment: Most of them support “multi-city.”  If all legs are the same day, isn’t that pretty much what you asked for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the question is "which flight engine lets me filter via (unusual request)", I've found the answer to almost always be [ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com). Using it, you can do searches requiring a certain transit point using their advanced routing codes.

Specifically, adding `X:MAN` to a search would require a transfer in Manchester.

[image: Animation of how to add transfer in Manchester]

Your results would then be only flights that have stops in Manchester. You can then [book the results from ITA Matrix using a tool like BookWithMatrix](https://bookwithmatrix.com)

I think Hipmunk used to also have a similar feature, but they unfortunately seem to have gotten rid of it. Best of luck!

Comment: Cool GIF! I should've been make it too, if I wasn't too lazy:)